# Eclipse Linux stock "Hello World"-app doesn't run

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've been developing with C++ in VS2010 but now I am trying to convert
my apps to build and run under Linux. So I've installed Eclipse Indigo
and the CDT package on an Ubuntu linux machine.

When I create the stock "Hello World"-project for C++, I get the
*classic* "Binary not found" error message. I've combed the internet,
but found no solution.

Through my findings I have gone to:

```
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor
```

and changed the `Current Toolchain` from Linux GCC to MinGW GCC.
But after rebuilding the project I still have the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the error *classic* if the interwebs have no solution? And why would you switch to MinGW when using Linux?

Comment: +1 for the mingw question. That stuff is Windows-only.

Comment: do you have gcc installed? does Eclipse now the paths?

Comment: good point, I switched back to Linux GCC.
I assume gcc is installed and eclipse knows the path??
In my project, I have a folder called includes which has:
/usr/include;
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu;
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include;
/usr/lib/gcc/x84_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed;
/usr/local/include

Comment: I found many cases of people with the error, none of their solutions work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gcc package doesn't necessarily include the C++ compiler. Try:

```
whereis g++
```

on the commandline (or `g++ -v`) to check if it is installed...

Comment: ok, when I did whereis g++
I got: g++:

Does that mean it is not installed?

Comment: @user1601045: so then it's not installed.  Use `apt` or whatever to look for it, then install the package. (if it were installed, there would be a path after the colon)